# What purpose does the site-selector under assets fulfill?

Tags: assets, sites

I'm kind of confused about the site selector under Assets, because from what I can gather it actually doesn't do anything? See this screenshot, top left:

[image]

I was first under the impression that I would only see assets that have been uploaded for a specific site, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Every user seem to see all content for a volume, meaning I would have to create a volume per site in order to separate them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assets aren't technically multi-site, in that it's currently not possible to limit Volumes to specific Sites, and all uploaded Assets will be available across all Sites, regardless of which Site it was uploaded from.

Assets *titles* and custom fields can be translated, though. So the purpose of the Site selector in the Assets index is to have the titles and any custom field values render with a specific Site's translations.

Comment: Ah, then it makes sense. So to separate them per site I just create a Volume per site as well and I can restrict access via there. Thanks!